# How to disply output as a table in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Usually, when i do `df.head()` on jupyter notebote, it gives me a nice table format, but suddenly it is giving me the following.

I am sure what changed? can you help with displaying output as a table on jupyter notebook?

[image]

data

```
                                       address    date  \
0  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  2016Q3   
1  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  2016Q4   
2  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  2017Q1   
3  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  2017Q2   
4  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000  2017Q3   

     tokens_USD  
0  3.990440e+01  
1  3.869824e+03  
2  8.905545e+03  
3  7.586588e+04  
4  1.413279e+08
```

Comment: you can use pandas

Comment: i tried `df = pd.DataFrame(df)` and `df.head()` nothing changes

Comment: no this is not the way.

Comment: can you tell me the way then?

Comment: ok  let me do that

Comment: can you provide the sample data

Comment: i added the output.

Comment: can you please tell me about address?

Comment: ?? it is just a wallet address. I tried using `display`, and also not working. Jupyter always displays df nicely in a table format, and I am not sure what happened, and it is displaying this crappy format now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251079/discussion-between-tanveer-ahmad-and-olive).

Comment: If [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75097183/8508004) is an improved post about this same issue, then this one should be deleted.